# Style from singleton not updated during build

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am trying to style my application through a style singleton `Style.qml` that I register using `qmlRegisterSingletonType`. When I make changes to the singletons qml file these do not get updated when rebuildung the application.

The following behavior leads me to believe that this is a caching problem: When I add new values to the top of the style file all the old values get shifted accordingly. For example looking at the file given below, if I add another line to the fontsizes this shifting leads to any item with a value of `backgroundColorHighlight` being displayed with the color of `backgroundColor` inside the application. So the color is being replaced with the value of line it used to be in.

Where can I find the cache file (if that is the problem), that is responsible for this strange behavior and clear it manually?

Steps I have taken so far:

- Cleaned the project through Qt Creator
- Clened the project manually through deleting the build folder
- Checked for and `.qmlc` files
- Added `QML_DISABLE_DISK_CACHE` to .pro file
- Ran `qmake` before rebuilding

Now I am all out of ideas. Is there any other place where Qt Creator / qmake can "hide" cache files?

Style.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.8

QtObject {
    //basic fonts
    property int fontSizeSmall: 8
    property real fontSizeMedium: 10
    property real fontSizeLarge: 14
    property string primaryFontColor: "#eeeeee"

    //backgrounds
    property string backgroundColorTransparent: "#4a4a4a88"
    property string backgroundColor: "#4a4a4a"
    property string backgroundHighlight: "#9a9a9a"
    property string backgroundColorLight: "#7a7a7a"

    property string dragTileBackgroundColor: "#5a5a5a"
    property string titleBarColor: "#3a3a3a"

    property color borderDarkColor: "#3a3a3a"

    property string mapMarkerFavorite: "#00ff00";
    property string mapMarker: "#ff3333";
    property string mapMarkerHighlight: "#ff8888";

    property string miniMapFillColor: "#ffffff"
    property string miniMapBorderColor: "#ffffff"
    property real miniMapBorderWidth: 1
    property real particleMiniMapOpacity: 0.5

    property int listElementHeight: 30
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming windows, the cache should be in:

`users\yourUser\AppData\Local\yourApp\cache\qmlcache`.

There is a known [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58486), which I actually [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903160/presence-and-location-of-a-property-in-a-qml-singleton-source-results-in-arbitra), disabling the caching via `qputenv("QML_DISABLE_DISK_CACHE", "1");` in `main.cpp` before you instantiate the QML engine will deal with a caching problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for documenting the bug! Is seems a little bit silly to me, that project related data should be stored in the user folder.

Comment: That's how windows does it. It is platform dependent. Standard system paths and such.